# How to combine two files in Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

i am learning Alteryx and have ran into my first issue. I have an excel file that i am using as one source. The files has two sheets with the same data, but the second sheet does not have headers.

I wanted to see if there was a way to combine the two sheets into one, within Alteryx using column position instead of headers since the second does not have them. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to input the file twice, once for each sheet.
For the 2nd sheet make sure to click on the option that the first row contains Data

Then you can use the Union tool --> Auto Config by position --> Set a specific order (Check). See image links below.

[First Row Contains Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2U2R.png)

[Union Tool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD04Z.png)

[Sheet 1 Example Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbluJ.png)

[Sheet 2 Example Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xRmx.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0i1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both their Join (https://help.alteryx.com/20213/designer/join-tool) and Union (https://help.alteryx.com/20213/designer/union-tool) tools have a "Record Position" option which is exactly what you're requesting. See the links for details.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it only added the fields from the second sheet to the right of the first sheet. Basically adding them as new columns with the first field as a header.

Comment: I don't have Alteryx any more but I'm pretty sure you can drag columns to force them to match by position. Or, you can also apply the the headings from the first data set to the second: see an example here: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/Apply-header-from-one-file-to-another-data-file/td-p/740309